# Wordpress filtering post_mime_type

Tags: php, wordpress, jplayer

I have been struggling with this for some time now and would really appreciate some help!

I am trying to populate html5 audio player with 2 codexes in Wordpress media library.

I am using the wp function get_posts and created one filter for post_mime_types 'ogg'. I have set the parameters for post_mime_type in get_posts's $args. Now I want to loop over and sort them into the audio player list as $mp3 and $ogg.

```
    $ogg = wp_get_attachment_url( $audio_attachment->post_mime_type="application/ogg" );
```

... in the code below but not outputting anything:

```
        <?php
         $query_audio_args = array(
           'post_type' => 'attachment',
           'post_mime_type' =>'application/ogg,audio',
           'post_status' => 'inherit',
           'posts_per_page' => -1,
      );

      $audio_attachments = get_posts($query_audio_args);
            foreach ( $audio_attachments as $audio_attachment ) {
                // Trying to sort them into $ogg, $aif and $mp3
                $ogg = wp_get_attachment_url( $audio_attachment->ID);

                $mp3 = wp_get_attachment_url( $audio_attachment-ID);

                $tracks[] = '{
                    title:"'.$audio_attachment->post_title.'",
                    mp3:"'.$mp3.'",
                    oga:"'.$ogg.'",
                    aif:"'.$aif.'"
                }';
                $alltracks = implode(',',$tracks);
            }
    ?>
```

Edit:
I also tried this, with the intention of creating a multiple array, but got stuck accessing the values:

```
            <?php
$query_audio_args = array(
           'post_type' => 'attachment',
           'post_mime_type' =>'application/ogg',
           'post_status' => 'inherit',
           'posts_per_page' => -1,
      );                

      $audio_attachments = get_posts($query_audio_args);
        $ogg = array();
            foreach ( $audio_attachments as $uk => $uv ) {                  
             $ogg[] = $uv->guid;                            
            }
         $query_audio_args1 = array(
           'post_type' => 'attachment',
           'post_mime_type' =>'audio',
           'post_status' => 'inherit',
           'posts_per_page' => -1,
      );                

     $audio_attachments1 = get_posts($query_audio_args1);
        $mp3 = array();
            foreach ( $audio_attachments1 as $ak => $av ) {                     
                $mp3[] = $av->guid;             
            }

        $audio = array(
                $ogg,
                $mp3
        );
        print_r($audio);
        foreach($audio as $k =>$v)
                    $tracks[] = '{
                        title:"'.$uv->post_title.'",
                        mp3:"'.$mp3->guid.'",
                        oga:"'.$uv->guid.'",
                        aif:"'.$aifv->guid.'"
                    }';
            $alltracks = implode(',',$tracks);                          
    ?>
```